# Is there a painless workflow for creating/saving/editing different android density drawables?

Tags: android, drawable

I am saving 4 copies of every image in my game, each with a different density.  They are saved in the relevant res/drawable-* folder, and it seems to be working great on various devices.

So, currently, I open up photoshop, and have one psd for each image.  I edit the vector's appropriately, change the density, and save the image in the appropriate folder.   I have to do this 4 times, for every image.  It takes forever, and I am trying to avoid getting sloppy and messing up one density of one image and not noticing it.

Is there a better way to this?  When you have to create and edit your drawables over the course of development, how do you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out batch processing in Photoshop. It will be the same thing you do, only automated
http://howto.wired.com/wiki/Batch_Process_Images_in_Photoshop

Comment: Thanks!  It looks like I will have to create 4 `Action`s, for changing the density and saving the image for each of the 4 possible densities.  I'll have to see if I can use an `Action` to run another `Action` so I can have a one click super `Action` to do all 4.

Comment: It may even be possible to run it as a script from terminal, for an entire folder of images. I know it can be done in GIMP and I'm pretty sure Photoshop has supports scripting as well.

Comment: I'll have to take a look at GIMP.  Photoshop can't do this too well-- I can't seem to just create an action for *ever* mdpi pic, I need to have a unique action for every picture and every density... Unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @edthethird this should be a good place to start http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/